# How to access @public instance variable from another class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, public-fields

I know it's possible to define public instance variable with @public keyword.
However, Objective-C syntax does not allow accessing other class' variable.
What features should I expected from @public Ivar? Or how do I access other class' Ivars?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Objective-C, as a superset of C, definitely does allow the access of public instance variables from outside the class's implementation. Now, the reason you may have heard that it *isn't allowed* is that it is highly discouraged. In most cases, if you want to access an instance variable outside an implementation context, you should be using accessors and mutators (properties).

An Objective-C class really boils down to a plain-old C struct with an `isa` field (that's what makes it an object), where the public fields are accessible. Since when we are dealing with instances of classes, we are working a pointer to an object (special struct). Thus, we access public fields using `->`.

Here's an example:

```
@interface SomebodyIsntEncapsulating : NSBadIdea {
  @public
  NSString *badIdea;
  BOOL shouldntDoIt;

  @protected
  NSString *ahThatsBetterThankGod;

  @private
  NSString *sweetThanksNowEvenMySubclassesCantTouchMe;
}
```

Now, in some completely different context, we could have:

```
SomebodyIsntEncapsulating *whatOh = [[SomebodyIsntEncapsulating alloc]
                                       initWithDanger:kDangerLevelEpicBraceYourself];
whatOh->badIdea = [@"I'm a public field. Make sure to retain or copy me!" copy];
NSLog(@"Please! Write some accessors and mutators!: %@", whatOh->badIdea);
```

I hope that helped you!

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. This is just what I want to know!

Comment: Haha that made my morning. Good answer

Answer (score 6):

You can access it like  using -> (member by pointer) operator like you normally access members of a c-structure (note that you always have a pointer to an object in obj-c):

```
...
@public
int a;
...

myObject->a = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to write accessor methods to do that. Object-oriented design implies that a class shouldn't care about internal structure of objects of another class.

That said, *id* is just a pointer, so you can do obj->ivar, provided you know what you're doing and there is no way to write a proper accessor method.