# Getting Exceptions in function call-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C. I am porting the cpp code to Objective C.

```
pMsg->TxCreateImage((INT8U*)m_cData.m_abTxMsgImage,m_cData.m_nTxImageSize);

TxCreateImage((INT8U*)pData,int uLen)
{
 func definition;
}
```

TxCreateImage is a function call.
m_cData is the object of another class.

Is this Objective C equivalent correct.

```
Data* pMsg = [[Data alloc]init];
Ds* m_cData;

[pMsg TxCreateImage:(int *)[m_cData m_abTxMsgImage] :(int)[m_cData m_nTxImageSize]];

- (void)TxCreateImage:(int*)pData :(int)uLen
{
 //func definition;
}
```

I am getting exceptions like,

```
-[Packet m_nTxImageSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100831e00
2011-05-04 17:11:07.756 Test-packetCreation[4633:a0f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Ds m_nTxImageSize]: unrecognized 
selector sent to instance 0x100831e00'
```

Comment: Also, in objective-c we tend to put descriptions in our method signatures. I.e. `[object doSuperCoolMethodUsingInt:i withString:name];` - it just makes the code more readable :)

Comment: This would not compile. Did you type it in the browser or is this actually what you have? eg [m_cData m_nTxImageSize)]

Comment: @fakeAccount22:Sorry I mistakenly put the ')' while editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize m_cData for one. And i'm not so sure about passing a pointer to integer; If that doesn't work try looking at the return type of m_nTxImageSize;

Unrecognised selector means it can't access/see the method called by m_nTxImageSize

Comment: sorrry i made a mistake here m_abTxImage and m_nTxImageSize are variables.How to pass variables of one class to another.

Answer (score 1):

Huge difference betwwen Objective-C and C++:

=> **Message send are late bound.**

You should get the habit of having does kind of error.
Look in you `Ds` class definition and see if you have an accessor `-m_abTxMsgImage`.
Remeber that all instance variable (memeber for C++ guys) are protected.

If you want to make it public you have to use the `@public` directive.
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182439/how-to-access-public-instance-variable-from-another-class-in-objective-c)

Also the naming of your method `-TxCreateImage::` is not the best way to of nameing method in objective-c.

Prefer something like `-createImageText:size:`

For accessors set method are named `setMyInstVar` and get method `myInstVar`. Also it is not common to add the `m_` to instance variable.

Accessor can be create automaticaly using the `@synthesize` directive which follow the convention I told you above.

Comment: will change and make my code as readble as you have said me to do.