# Calling A Variable in a different View Controller iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

So i have two view controllers home, second. I create a variable in home and want to call it in the second UIViewController. I get an error saying:

Use of undeclared identifier 'plusNumber'

Please let me know why i am not connecting the second UIViewController with the variable in home. I imported the header file home.h into the second.h file.

Thanks.

Code is below:
**home.h**

```
@interface homeViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    int plusNumber;  
}
- (IBAction)plusSign:(id)sender;
```

**home.m**

```
- (IBAction)plusSign:(id)sender {

    if(self.plusNumber == 0)
    {
        self.plusNumber = @"1";
    } 
    else 
    {
        self.plusNumber = @"0";
    }

}
```

**second.h**

```
#import "home.h"

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *output;
```

second.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.output.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", plusNumber];
}
```

Comment: You will need to create @property in home.h to access this in other VC. `@property (nonatomic) int plusNumber;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

You must declare it as a public variable

So you must change your home.h interface to

```
@interfacehomeViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
 {
  @public
  int plusNumber;  
 }
```

more info: [How to access @public instance variable from another class in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182439/how-to-access-public-instance-variable-from-another-class-in-objective-c)

Comment: I have tried both suggestions and am stilling getting the same error message. I read through the links as well and think that i am doing what they say to do but it still says Use of undeclared identifier 'plusNumber'.

Answer (score 0):

Use properties.

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) int plusNumber;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In home.m, create a segue from view1 to view2 and give it a segueIdentifier
Import second.h inside home.h file

```
- (IBAction)plusSign:(id)sender {

if(self.plusNumber == 0)
{
    self.plusNumber = @"1";
[self performSegueWithItentifier @"segueName"];
} 
else 
{
    self.plusNumber = @"0";
   [self performSegueWithItentifier @"segueName"];
}

}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
  Second secondInstance = [segue destinationViewController];
secondInstance.output = self.plusNumber;

}
```

In Second.h  remove the import statement or it will get into a memory leak cycle
Make one NSString named 
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *outputStr;

```
 viewDidLoad{
   self.output.text = self.outputStr;
   }
```

and voila 
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**home.h**

```
@property (nonatomic) int plusNumber;
```

**home.m**

```
- (IBAction)plusSign:(id)sender {
   [self performSegueWithItentifier @"segue"];
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue"]){
        SecondViewController *controller = 
                         (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.plusNumberString  = (self.plusNumber == 0) ?  @"1" :  @"0";
    }
}
```

**second.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *plusNumberString;
```

**second.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSLog(@"_plusNumberString = %@", _plusNumberString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C, way of coding we call this as getter & setters.

You can create your getters and setters by declaring the property to the variable.
Since you're using int datatype, just assign it as below

```
@Property(nonatomic, assign) int plusNumber
```

## HomeViewController.h

```
@interface homeViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    int plusNumber;  
}
@Property(nonatomic, assign) int plusNumber
- (IBAction)plusSign:(id)sender;
```

## SecondViewController.m

```
#import "homeViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    homeViewController *homecontroller = [[homeViewController alloc] init]
    self.output.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", homecontroller.plusNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HomeViewController.h
    @interfacehomeViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
     {

      NSUInteger plusNumber;  
     }
     @property (nonatomic,assign) NSUInteger plusNumber;

HomeViewController.m
@synthesize plusNumber;
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "homeViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    homeViewController *homecontroller = [[homeViewController alloc] init]
    self.output.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", homecontroller.plusNumber];
}
```

Hope it helps.